# Where can I get a history of METARs?

Tags: datasets, metar

Is there a place where past METARs are logged?

Suppose I want all the METAR for a given airport from October 1st to October 15th 2015. Where can I find them?

If it matters, I'm looking in particular for METARs from French airports.

Comment: Only source I know of is http://www.aviationweather.gov/dataserver (US primarily, but does seem to have  METARs from around the world). But, it only has access to the past 3 days worth of METARs.

Comment: I'm looking forward to reading the answers on this question. One thing I've been looking into lately are METAR trends which can be helpful when reviewing weather for flight planning purposes.

Comment: Also worthwhile to check Weather Underground -- they have a pretty good history of METAR reports for the US, and they may for international airports as well.

Comment: @mins Ogimet works.

Comment: @RalphJ Do you have a link?

Comment: The duplicate question has an answer which answers this one, although the original question only asked about airport ceilometer data.  Thanks for asking the question though, as it will enable people in the future to find that one!

Comment: The following link is specific to one airport (KJFK) for one particular day, but it shows the repository of Weather Underground METAR reports: http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KJFK/2015/10/12/DailyHistory.html?req_city=Kennedy%20International&req_state=NY&req_statename=New%20York&reqdb.zip=11499&reqdb.magic=4&reqdb.wmo=99999&theprefset=SHOWMETAR&theprefvalue=1

Comment: @usernumber  I posted a more complete explanation on the question which this one is marked as a duplicate of -- [here] (http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14596/is-there-a-database-of-airport-ceilometer-raw-data/22174#22174)  I actually like THIS question better, but since it points to the other, it's all good, I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OgiMet](http://www.ogimet.com/metars.phtml.en) `Professional information about meteorological conditions in the world` is such a site that offers 30-day history for METARs/SPECIs and TAFs reports.

The coverage is said to be worldwide. Here is a glance at the query interface:

[image]

The site states these conditions of use for the reports:

> About all the codified met. reports (SYNOPS, METAR ...), the copyright
> are from every country or source institution. To use them,
> read [WMO resolution 40](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/im/wmocovr.htm).

(essentially it says it's free for use.)

The site accepts requests for up to 31 days at once.

Example: METARs for month of September 2020 for [Orly / LFPO](http://www.ogimet.com/display_metars2.php?lang=en&lugar=lfpo&tipo=ALL&ord=DIR&nil=SI&fmt=html&ano=2020&mes=09&day=01&hora=00&anof=2020&mesf=09&dayf=31&horaf=18&minf=59&send=send):

[image]

Comment: this website is terrible. no matter how much data I query it fails to return

Comment: @usernumber look at the [NCEP MADIS archive](https://madis-data.ncep.noaa.gov/madisPublic1/data/archive/) they have METAR data going back to March 2006.

Comment: I find the site works fine but seems not to retain data for as long as one year.  For example today is Dec 4 2020 and this search for data for November 29 2019 failed http://www.ogimet.com/display_metars2.php?lang=en&lugar=KAVK&tipo=ALL&ord=REV&nil=SI&fmt=html&ano=2019&mes=11&day=29&hora=12&anof=2019&mesf=11&dayf=29&horaf=17&minf=59&send=send but one for the same date in 2020 worked fine.  PS perhaps I spoke too soon, after several more searches I just got the message "#Sorry, Your quota limit for slow queries rate has been reached"

Comment: @quietflyer: Thanks, I wasn't aware and I get the same message. [Related](https://sourceforge.net/p/metaf2xml/support-requests/19/?page=1&limit=25#cff7) (a METAR decoder using Ogimet source).