# How can I get prior days weather information?

Tags: weather

If I want to get airmet information for prior days, like say last week or last month, how can I do that? Specific instructions would be appreciated.

(So, this would be information like winds aloft and ceilings.)

Comment: Looks like this may be a "resource location" question (and thus off topic).

Comment: Weather Underground used to have a good archive, at least for METAR reports, which would give you ceilings. Dunno if they still do, nor about winds aloft. Maybe ADDS or NOAA - they have a lot on their servers.

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22086/where-can-i-get-a-history-of-metars .  Note the comments under q and a's.  Also https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14596/is-there-a-database-of-airport-ceilometer-raw-data.

Answer (score 2):

You can get past weather for particular weather reporting stations from the National Weather Service. The help page has several different options, including how to obtain certified weather (used in accident investigations and litigation). The website is located [here.](https://www.weather.gov/help-past-weather)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](https://weather.rap.ucar.edu/) and select Upper Air. Also available are Surface Weather (metars), Satellite imagery, and Radar.  The Upper Air selection allows user selection and review of individual maps of winds aloft for any image over the last 10 days, or as an animation of frames for these maps over a time period of up to the last 10 days. The site is the Research Application Laboratory, University Corporation for Atmospheric Research, NCAR.

The Naval Research Laboratory, Monterrey, may provide other imagery of interest regarding upper air maps and animations at this [link](https://www.nrlmry.navy.mil/).